# Conditional sum using linq for Or condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

When I use two conditions joined by an `OR`, the result is not correct for SQL Server.

How can I fix it?

This is my LINQ code and result in SQL (that reflection created for me):

```
  query.Where(p => ((p.Code == "100000") Or p.Code.EndsWith("200")))
  query.Where(p => (p.year == "2015"))}
```

I added this `where` clause at runtime, now I add another extension method and it's not working:

```
query.sum(p => p.value)
```

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in
>   a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

SQL translated:

```
SELECT SUM([e].[Value])
FROM [acc].[Data161] AS [e]
WHERE (CASE
          WHEN RIGHT([e].[Code], LEN(N'201')) = N'201'
             THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
       END | 
       CASE
          WHEN RIGHT([e].[Code], LEN(N'199')) = N'199'
             THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
       END) 
  AND ([e].[SetadCode] = N'161')
```

The correct SQL should have `= 1` before the `AND`.

But without sum its works fine and add a `= 1` to SQL command

Comment: The error is occurring because you have two WHERE.  Instead us either 'And' or 'Or' into your 1st WHERE.

Comment: Wrong SQL *always* is a framework bug. Please report it.

Comment: @jdweng i added this where clouses by some conditions at runtime, its not the problem

Comment: @usr i added  an issue in github :( 
I hope my code is wrong and someone give me a better way. by the way i added an isssue

Comment: Did you try this : query.Where(p => (p.year == "2015") And ((p.Code == "100000") Or p.Code.EndsWith("200")))

Comment: @jdweng yes, same result returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `Or` is not a valid C# operator

```
.Where(p => ((p.Code == "100000") Or p.Code.EndsWith("200")))
```

If you change it to `||`, the query translates correctly and executes w/o issue.

Looking at the generated SQL, I'm pretty sure you have used the bitwise or operator (`|`) instead, in which case I get the same error. While this could be a EF Core translator bug, you shouldn't be using it anyway - use the logical or `||` operator and the generated SQL will not have all that `CASE WHEN` expressions, but a typical simple `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: EF translates it with Case When, both of them are lack of "= 1" after adding another condition to linq query

Comment: No, it's not. I've checked everything I wrote before posting it as an answer. Again, make sure you are using `||` and not `|`. Also check your EF Core version. Tested and working under EF Core v.1.1.0

Comment: appreciate that, i checked Ef 1.1.0, and its works fine with `Expression.OrElse()` thanks a lot. you saved me, why i never thought about that at all? :)) i just read ur answer excuse me for that.

Comment: You are welcome. No problem, we are all on hurry sometimes :) Just be very careful with EF Core - very unstable, every minor version could improve something, but also break another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `||` instead of `or`

```
query.Where(p => ((p.Code == "100000") || p.Code.EndsWith("200")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but does not address the linq part of the question.

I would expect the `where` clause to look like this:

```
where (code = '100000' or p.code like '%200') and (p.year = '2015')
```

All that bit manipulation that is generated is jarring.  Note that the above code is ANSI-standard SQL as well.

Comment: me too, but as I said, I use reflection and add my conditions with extension methods, my project is a big reporting project so it's not a good idea to hardcode my where clauses to be close to standards